# Proof for sequent (Logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm currently trying to prove the following:

[http://i.imgur.com/dACOdOS.png](https://i.imgur.com/dACOdOS.png)

And this is what I've come up with so far:

[http://i.imgur.com/mC69m5l.png](https://i.imgur.com/mC69m5l.png)

And now I'm stuck. Perhaps the next step might be to eliminate for all x?

I'm sorry for using links, but it seems like I'm not allowed to do it otherwise due to needed reputation point.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The rules I'm allowed to use in the proof: http://i.imgur.com/hf9xqr1.png

Comment: The first link - http://i.imgur.com/removed.png - does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$∀x (P(x) → Q(x))$ --- premise

2) $∀x¬Q(x)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $P(x_0)$ --- assumed [b] : $x_0$ fresh

4) $P(x_0) → Q(x_0)$ --- from 1) by $\forall$-e

5) $¬Q(x_0)$ --- from 2) by $\forall$-e

6) $Q(x_0)$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\to$-e

7) $\bot$ --- from 5) and 6) by $\lnot$-e

8) $\lnot P(x_0)$ --- from 3) and 7) by $\lnot$-i, discharging [b]

9) $\forall x \lnot P(x)$ --- from 8) by $\forall$-i

> 10) $∀x¬Q(x) \to ∀x¬P(x)$ --- from 2) and 9) by $\to$-i, discharging [a].

Comment: Thank you very much. As I have understood, you're "creating" the variable x0 after P(x0). How come? As you can see in my attempt, I've placed the x0 before. Would this then be wrong? http://i.imgur.com/eEWzc46.png

Comment: @JonathanK - no, I've "created" it when I need it, in order to "instantiate" $\forall x$. With a ‘fresh’ variable $x_0$, we are able to prove a formula $φ[x_0/x]$ with $x_0$ in it, then (because $x_0$ is fresh) we can derive $∀xφ$. The important point is that $x_0$ is a new variable which doesn’t occur anywhere outside its box. Since we
assumed nothing about this $x_0$, anything would work in its place; hence the conclusion $∀xφ$." [page 110].

Comment: Well, I think I have misunderstood something then. Would this: http://i.imgur.com/eEWzc46.png then be right, or do I need to adjust something?

Comment: I think I got it: I'm creating a new box inside x0's box, so I actually "create" x0 before I'm using it. You're "creating" x0 when it is needed. But as long as x0  doesn't occur outside of its box, it shouldn't matter I guess.

Comment: @JonathanK - your new version is correct :-)